# Mongodb one to many relation load in nestjs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, relationship

I have found many questions asking sort of the same thing but I can't figure out what I am missing. As the title says I am trying to load a one-to-many relationship with NestJS from a MongoDB entity.

The schema is:
**A category has many reports**

What I have written so far is these files (with all the classic NestJS modules architecture):

`report.entity.ts`

```js
import { SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose/dist';
import { Prop, Schema } from "@nestjs/mongoose/dist/decorators";
import { ApiProperty, ApiPropertyOptional } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { Expose } from "class-transformer";
import { ExposeId } from "../../helpers/expose-id.helper";
import mongoose, { Schema as MongooseSchema } from 'mongoose';
import { Category } from '../categories/category.entity';

@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Report {
    @ApiProperty({ readOnly: true })
    @ExposeId()
    _id: string

    @ApiPropertyOptional()
    @Expose()
    @Prop()
    name: string

    @ApiPropertyOptional({ type: () => Category })
    @Expose()
    @Prop({ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Category" })
    category: Category

    @ApiProperty()
    @Expose()
    @Prop()
    updatedAt: Date

    @ApiProperty()
    @Expose()
    @Prop()
    createdAt: Date

    @ApiPropertyOptional()
    @Expose()
    @Prop()
    deletedAt: Date

}
export const ReportSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Report);
```

`category.entity.ts`

```js
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from "@nestjs/mongoose/dist";
import { ApiProperty, ApiPropertyOptional } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { Expose } from "class-transformer";
import { IsNotEmpty } from "class-validator";
import { ExposeId } from "../../helpers/expose-id.helper";
import { Report } from "../reports/report.entity";
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Category {
    @ApiProperty({ readOnly: true })
    @ExposeId()
    _id: string

    @ApiProperty()
    @Expose()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @Prop()
    name: string

    @ApiProperty({ type: () => [Report] })
    @Expose()
    @Prop({ type: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId], ref: "Reports" })
    reports: Report[]

    @ApiProperty()
    @Expose()
    @Prop()
    updatedAt: Date

    @ApiProperty()
    @Expose()
    @Prop()
    createdAt: Date

    @ApiPropertyOptional()
    @Expose()
    @Prop()
    deletedAt: Date

}
export const CategorySchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Category);
```

I create a report with

```js
@Injectable()
export class ReportsService {

    constructor(
        @InjectModel('Report') private readonly reportModel: Model<Report>,
    ) { }

    createReport(report: Report, plain: boolean = true): Promise<Report> {
        return this.reportModel.create(report).then(obj => plain ? obj.toObject() : obj);
    }
}
```

I load a category with

```js
@Injectable()
export class CategoriesService {
    private defaultPopulate: string[] = ['reports'];

    constructor(
        @InjectModel('Category') private readonly categoryModel: Model<Category>,
    ) { }

    findCategory(id: string, plain: boolean = true): Promise<Category> {
        return this.categoryModel.findById(id, undefined, { lean: plain, populate: this.defaultPopulate }).exec();
    }
}
```

For inserting the records I create the category, then I create separately the reports associated with the category.

If I want to load a report, the many-to-one works correctly loading also the category. If I want a category with all of its reports, it doesn't.

What am I missing if I want to load all the reports of a category without requesting to load the category and then manually inject all the reports with the particular category id? Do I need to save the report id to its category after creating the report? My use case won't create any report anytime when creating/updating a category, that section of the database will function like a normal relational SQL DB.